# (Android) How do I prevent crashes while developing/testing from going to google play crash reports?

Tags: android

This makes it hard to distinguish between real crash at the hands of the users and developing time crash.

Does the crashing and ANRs reported to google play reduce reach of my app to users.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create different flavors of your project.

- If flavor1 is in play store and flavor2 is your next version, then
  when developing you can remove the crashlytics compile statement from
  Gradle scripts and continue your development.
- When you are done with the development, you can add the compile back
  and build a release version of this flavor.

Hope this will work.